# ModuleNotFoundError when using venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

I have just installed Python 3.8 on a Mac Catalina machine.
I have created a new virtual env using PyCharm and installed the `slackclient` package using PyCharm's preferences.
However, whichever way I try to run the app, I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'` error. 
I have verified that it is installed in the OS terminal (zsh):

```
(venv) *** pip list            
Package       Version
------------- -------
aiohttp       3.6.2  
async-timeout 3.0.1  
attrs         19.3.0 
chardet       3.0.4  
idna          2.9    
multidict     4.7.5  
pip           20.0.2 
setuptools    46.1.3 
slackclient   2.5.0  
yarl          1.4.2  
(venv) *** python studiobot.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "studiobot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from slackclient import SlackClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `print(sys.path)`? Is your virtual environment in that list?

Comment: @Josh
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/purrplebread/Documents/501/studio-501-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']. 
Seems to be fine

Comment: Most likely PyCharm is not using the venv interpreter

Comment: @NomadMonad I have mentioned that the issue persists in the OS terminal

Comment: Then the module is probably not called `slackclient`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using something like

```py
from slack import WebClient
```

https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient#sending-a-message-to-slack

Comment: Thank you, looks like it is the solution.